# Vbscript - Fill 2d array error

Tags: vbscript

I need to create a 2D array in vbscript and fill it manually.

I have done:

```
Dim MyArray
MyArray= Array(9,11)
```

But when i try to fill the array i get the following error:

```
MyArray(0,0) = 2
MyArray(0,1) = test
...
index out of bounds
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: `Array(9,11)` is a native VBS function, which returns 1-dimensional array with elements `9` and `11`. You should declare 2-dimensional array in a proper way: `Dim MyArray(9,11)`.

Comment: it is working, thanks  @omegastripes